# Python - re.DOTALL resulting in "None" output

Tags: python

I am trying to grab 2 ipv6 addresses from the following code:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
with open('show_ipv6_intf.txt') as f:
    show_ipv6_int = f.read()
match = re.search(r'^\s+(\S+)\s\[VALID\]\s+(\S+).*', show_ipv6_int,flags=re.M)

ipv6_1 = match.group(1)
ipv6_2 = match.group(2)
ipv6_list = []


ipv6_list.append(ipv6_1)
ipv6_list.append(ipv6_2)

print(ipv6_list)
```

---

For breadth,

Here's the file being used:

```
Ethernet2/4, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 40
  IPv6 address:
    2001:11:2233::a1/24 [VALID]
    2001:cc11:22bb:0:2ec2:60ff:fe4f:feb2/64
  IPv6 subnet:  2001::/24
  IPv6 link-local address: fe80::2ec2:60ff:fe4f:feb2 (default) [VALID]
  IPv6 virtual addresses configured: none
  IPv6 multicast routing: disabled
  IPv6 report link local: disabled
  IPv6 Forwarding feature: disabled
  IPv6 multicast groups locally joined:
      ff02::1:ff4f:feb2  ff02::2  ff02::1  ff02::1:ff00:a1
      ff02::1:ff4f:feb2  ff02::1:ff00:0
  IPv6 multicast (S,G) entries joined: none
  IPv6 MTU: 1500 (using link MTU)
  IPv6 unicast reverse path forwarding: none
  IPv6 load sharing: none
  IPv6 interface statistics last reset: never
  IPv6 interface RP-traffic statistics: (forwarded/originated/consumed)
    Unicast packets:      0/0/0
    Unicast bytes:        0/0/0
    Multicast packets:    0/18/0
    Multicast bytes:      0/2076/0
```

---

If i use flag "re.M" I retrieve desired results, but when I'm using "re.DOTALL" I yield the "None" boolean.  See below:

### with re.M

`C:\Users\Kenyone\.PyCharm2019.3\config\scratches>python week4lesson6.py ['2001:11:2233::a1/24', '2001:cc11:22bb:0:2ec2:60ff:fe4f:feb2/64']`

### with re.DOTALL

`C:\Users\Kenyone\.PyCharm2019.3\config\scratches>python week4lesson6.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "week4lesson6.py", line 7, in <module> ipv6_1 = match.group(1) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: `None` is not a boolean. But yes, it means that your regex no longer matches the input.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. Please show the *complete* version of the code *that causes the error*.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to gain from re.DOTALL?  It changes the behavior of the `.` in your regex pattern, but you only have one and it is not necessary.  Since it's followed by `*`, it can match zero times.  You could rewrite the pattern without that dot-star at the end and get the same behavior.

`r'^\s+(\S+)\s\[VALID\]\s+(\S+)'` should be identical and have no dots.

re.M is necessary because you have `^` and want it to match at the beginning of a line, not just at the beginning of the whole string.

You could use both flags together and it would work, but re.DOTALL isn't doing anything useful here.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The only reason I'm testing both is because I was actually learning the concepts behind both, and was doing an exercise that asked to use re.DOTALL instead of re.M, and I couldn't retrieve the desired results.  However, you just helped me out a lot by telling me the ^ is what's causing my re.DOTALL not to work, I removed that, and voila, .DOTALL now works.  But i guess I don't quite understand the concept of "why", but thanks so much!

Comment: The DOTALL isn't doing anything.  Your pattern works the same with or without that flag.  This pattern doesn't show how that flag can change the matching behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* the `re.M` if you don't use a line assertion:

```
[ \t]*([\d:a-f/]+)[ \t]*\[VALID\]\s+([\d:a-f/]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pWz0e/1)

But that potentially makes the regex *slow*

With a line assertion, faster and with the character classes on each side of the `[VALID]` more specific:

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7pWz0e/2)

Python demo (with `txt` set to your example text):

```
>>> reg=re.compile(r'^[ \t]*([\d:a-f/]+)[ \t]*\[VALID\]\s+([\d:a-f/]+)', flags=re.M)
>>> reg.findall(txt)
[('2001:11:2233::a1/24', '2001:cc11:22bb:0:2ec2:60ff:fe4f:feb2/64')]
```

And with YOUR regex or THIS regex you don't need `re.S` which is a flag to have the `.` match a `\n`. If fact, your regex will only match a single first match if you add `re.S` since `.*` will now match to the end of the string:

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/LgEDSE/1)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a bit more under the hood of python, and good to know!  The exercise I was doing was calling for me to use the .DOTALL instead of .M, and I was hitting a wall because I was using ^ with .DOTALL and was getting "None"